# One drive API to list all drives for a one drive business account not working?

Tags: office365, onedrive, office365api

I have integrated one drive API for both one drive and one drive business.For One Drive I am able to use the /drives webservice, which returns a single drive.But for One Drive business this gives me 404 response.So, is this API only meant for One Drive?

Comment: Do you know if the calling user has a drive provisioned (I.e. does /drive return a non-404 response)?

Comment: The /drive returns a valid reponse, with details of default drive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call against a URL root. This is different for OneDrive and OneDrive for Business.

```
OneDrive - https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0

OneDrive for Business - https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0

SharePoint Online - https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/{site-relative-path}/_api/v2.0
```

Read the below link for more details

https://dev.onedrive.com/getting-started.htm